# How can I serialize std::vector<details> (details is a struct.)

Tags: c++11, serialization

I have a struct in c++11 , like:

```
struct objectv1 {
        matrix<float, 0, 1 > obj_descriptor;
        string person_name;
        matrix<rgb_pixel> p_obj_chip;
        string notes;

    };
```

and than:

```
std::vector<objectv1> object_deteails;
```

and pushing back to object_details data.

How can I serialize and deserialize the object_details  vector?
It could be helpfull for beginners like me

Thanks

Comment: Use a serialization library. There is cereal, protobuffer, a bunch of json-based libraries and more. Learning about the pain of integrating libraries is unfortunately an important aspect of C++.

Comment: struggling more than half day.  I am a java girl 8+ years experience. But stuck this point. c++ looks from different planet sometimes :)

Comment: I have the same problem.. :)

Comment: Yeah, C++ and Java have similar syntax and keywords but they mean different things. Also sometimes what is considered good in one language is considered bad in the other. You just have to go through the pain of learning a language again, no shortcut for you. But consider dropping by [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116940/c-questions-and-answers) which is better suited for beginner issues.

Comment: Give us a hint. How do you intend to serialise objectv1? Text or binary?

Comment: both could be usable for me Text or binary.  it will save my week :)

Comment: any help for this six pack muscle new Marry ?